# Can a Missing Directory in a Github Repository Cause the Following Dockerfile Error?

Tags: dockerfile, render.com

I am trying to set up PeerJS Server on Render.com from a copy on my Github. (The original Github of this is [here](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server).)

Render.com sets up everything automatically in the fields when I set up a webservice.

Within the Github root directory is a dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir /peer-server
WORKDIR /peer-server
COPY bin ./bin
COPY dist ./dist
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --production
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "bin/peerjs"]
CMD [ "--port", "9000", "--path", "/myapp" ]
```

As Render.com tries to set it up it has within its log, just before failing:

```
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM  Dockerfile:5
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM  --------------------
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM     3 |     WORKDIR /peer-server
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM     4 |     COPY bin ./bin
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM     5 | >>> COPY dist ./dist
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM     6 |     COPY package.json .
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM     7 |     RUN npm install --production
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM  --------------------
Jan 14 03:27:36 PM  error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref k0xqk3go2ko8jkmhel1pr1ugp::u02fc82vzv7zvmwdwr4k6r805: "/dist": not found
```

There is no `dist` directory in the Github Repository. Has something been modified and the Dockerfile not been updated?